# Circular Reference in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm getting a circular reference error in Microsoft Access SQL.

```
SELECT a.PlateNo, a.colm, a.alain
FROM (SELECT PlateNo, alain, min(InspectionDate) AS colm
      FROM [Vehicle Spot Check] GROUP BY PlateNo)
  AS a
INNER JOIN [Vehicle Spot Check] AS m
ON (a.alain = m.WithoutDefects) AND (a.colm = m.InspectionDate)
  AND (a.PlateNo = m.PlateNo);
```

I'm getting this error:

> ```
> Circular reference caused by alias '' in query definition's Select List.
> ```

I dont know which one because there is no specified field. My main suspect is `m.WithoutDefects` but I already double checked. Is there any way to find this? What I'm thinking is also the syntax after the "Inner Join" as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's got to do with either or both of your "AS".  If you have a column named `colm` or `m`, you cannot name the result of "AS" as a current column value.  Try replacing the `colm` and `m` with something else such as `colm_` and `m_`:

```
SELECT a.PlateNo, a.colm, a.alain
FROM (SELECT PlateNo, alain, min(InspectionDate) AS colm_
      FROM [Vehicle Spot Check] GROUP BY PlateNo)
  AS a
INNER JOIN [Vehicle Spot Check] AS m_
ON (a.alain = m.WithoutDefects) AND (a.colm = m.InspectionDate)
  AND (a.PlateNo = m.PlateNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am **Bhanu Bhanot** from **India**

USE THIS

> SELECT E.id AS ID,
>          E.dte AS Date,
>          E.Billno AS 'Bill No',
>          E.LRno AS 'LR No',
>          P1.PartyName AS 'Sender Party',
>          E.Qty,
>          E.PVT_Marka AS 'PVT Marka',
>          P2.PartyName AS 'Receiver Party',
>          E.Amount,
>          E.CGST,
>          E.SGST,
>          E.IGST,
>          E.TotalAmount AS 'Total Amount' FROM(Entry AS E
>        INNER JOIN Party AS P1 ON E.PartySenderId = P1.id)
>        LEFT JOIN Party AS P2 ON E.PartyReceiverId = P2.id ORDER BY E.id;

NOT THIS

> SELECT id AS ID,
>          E.dte AS Date,
>          E.Billno AS 'Bill No',
>          E.LRno AS 'LR No',
>          P1.PartyName AS 'Sender Party',
>          E.Qty,
>          E.PVT_Marka AS 'PVT Marka',
>          P2.PartyName AS 'Receiver Party',
>          E.Amount,
>          E.CGST,
>          E.SGST,
>          E.IGST,
>          E.TotalAmount AS 'Total Amount' FROM(Entry AS E
>        INNER JOIN Party AS P1 ON E.PartySenderId = P1.id)
>        LEFT JOIN Party AS P2 ON E.PartyReceiverId = P2.id ORDER BY id;

CAUSE

the `id` field is existing in both `Entry` and `Party` Table. To recognize the table should specify `E.id` instead of `id`

IT IS WORKING..